# Getting WindowsIdentity in a linux-based node.js express-app

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I have an express.js intra-net app running on linux, serving windows-domain users inside the company.

I need to get in server-code the name of the logged-in user on the machine where the browser-request has originated from.

On ASP.NET I write:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

Is there any such node.js equivalent?

Comment: No, browsers don't send the username to the server. I would be surprised if it is possible in ASP.NET, maybe a IE-specific feature?

Comment: Nope, just tried it before posting, got the domain\name correctly from a FF request to a visual-studio development-server (casini, not IIS)

Comment: That's because the above code returns the user the application runs under.